# Given a, b are integers. Show that GCD(a,b) = GCD(b,a).

Tags: divisibility

Where do I start?

I don't really understand what the difference is between the two. It seems so logic to me that I don't know how wich parts I should explain.

How to start, What is there to be shown?

Comment: What is your definition of $\gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: Can you give us a *precise* definition from your textbook of GCD(a,b)?

Comment: You are right it is obvious. I guess you can write $gcd(a,b)=sup\{s:s|a $ and $ s|b\}=gcd(b,a)$.

Answer (score 0):

> How to start, What is there to be shown?

I imagine that you are going through an exercise: you have an idea that you have some understanding about, and you are in the process of working through a rigorous development of it.

Typically, these things start with some sort of precise definition. You'll have to consult your book/notes to know what that is. But two typical ways to begin are as follows:

> $\gcd(a,b)$ is defined to be a nonnegative integer $c$ with the property that, whenever an integer $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $d$ also divides $c$.

or

> $\gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive number you can create by computing $ma + nb$, where $m,n$ are integers, or $0$ if $a=b=0$.

In both cases, if you swap $a$ and $b$, you get something different. Although, it is something different that is *very easy* to show is equivalent to the original. Your book/notes are likely to be very similar to this.